Construction of spin ½ representations of SO(p,q) from clifford algebras
There is a way of constructing spin ½ representations of SO(1,3) directly from the Clifford algebra $ \mathcal{C}\ell (1, 3) $ which is:
1 take a spin ½ representation of the Clifford algebra, for example the Pauli matrices
$ { \sigma_i }^2 = \pm \mathbb{1}  $
2 construct the generators of the lorentz algebra $ \mathfrak{so}(1, 3) $  in terms of these clifford algebra representations, for example
$ \ J_{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{2} \sigma_{\mu} \sigma_{\nu} $
3 exponentiate these generators to get a group representation
$ D[\Lambda] = \exp(\frac{1}{2} \theta^{\mu\nu} J_{\mu\nu}) $
One would then expect for this procedure to generalize to arbitrary signature and dimension. I am trying to prove this however, to do so we need a generalization of the Pauli matrices. Does such a thing exist? How do we construct this?

So as I understand you just want to construct the Spin group. This doesn't really have anything to do with Pauli matrices so long as you aren't looking for particular generators like $J_{\mu\nu}$. If you specifically want exponentials, then this depends on your definitions of $\mathrm{SO}(p,q)$ and $\mathrm{Spin}(p,q)$. If $$\mathrm{SO}(p,q)={\Lambda\in\mathrm O(p,q);:;\det\Lambda=1}$$ and $\mathrm{Spin}(p,q)$ is its double-cover then you cannot in general represent elements of $\mathrm{Spin}(p,q)$ as exponentials of bivectors.
